# Why do I lose precision when passing a c# double to a SQL procedure with varchar argument?

Tags: sql-server, string, type-conversion, double, varchar

I am working with a SQL Server stored procedure that takes, among other things, a string as a parameter. It is expected that the string will represent a number. Normally, I would use a numeric type for this, but this procedure does something that requires it to be a number.

I am experiencing problems with round-off. In order to simplify the problem, I wrote this procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.TestProc @s 
    VARCHAR(20)  
AS
    SELECT @s;
```

I call this procedure from C# code as follows.

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand()
{
    CommandText = "TestProc",
    CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure,
    Connection = myConnection
};

cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@s", -157.7181));

var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

reader.Read();

// Should get -157.7181, but get -157.718 instead
var x = reader[0];
```

The result is off by one ten-thousandth.

However, I get the correct result when I use the code below to add the parameter.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@s", "-157.7181"));
```

In other words, explicitly using a string for the number in c# yields the correct answer, while allowing it to be converted to a string implicitly creates a round-off error.

I can readily see that the solution to my problem is to explicitly cast my double value to a string before adding the parameter, but my question is: Why?

How can this be explained?

My Visual Studio version and SQL Server version are both 2008.

Comment: CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.TestProc @s decimal(18,4) AS
SELECT @s;

Comment: Why not?, the parameter for your sp is a string, so you should be using one

Comment: Why not?  It doesn't bother me that I need to cast the value to a string explicitly.  What bothers me is that allowing it to be cast implicitly causes a loss of precision for reasons that I don't understand.  I want to know what the reason is for this difference in behavior.

Comment: What is the statement in the stored procedure where this precision is being lost? More importantly, why are you using a string type to pass a decimal in the first place?

Comment: Because implicit conversion will use default precision which in your case is going to cause a loss of precision. Don't use the default when you care what the precision is (which should be every single time).

Comment: Yes, what @Sean said. By passing it as a string instead of a numeric, you're basically telling the whole stack, hey, here's a string I'm throwing at you, convert it to some kind of number, would you?

Comment: Why would you even *start* with passing a `double` into a `varchar` parameter? `SqlCommand`'s job is *not* to blindly convert types for you in the best manner possible (that's a bit context sensitive anyway).

Comment: Also, I *think* that double is an imprecise variable (I forget the correct technical term), that can lose precision.   If you were using a decimal type instead, it should convert as a string to the exact precision.   I *think*.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that's SQLs default behavior when converting from a float value to a string.  Look at this:

```
declare @f float = 157.7181
select @f, convert(varchar(20), @f), STR(@f, 18, 10)
```

resulting in:

```
(No column name)    (No column name)    (No column name)
157.7181            157.718             157.7181000000
```

From the Transact-SQL manual (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx):

*Values of float are truncated when they are converted to any integer type.
When you want to convert from float or real to character data, using the STR string function is usually more useful than CAST( ). This is because STR enables more control over formatting. For more information, see STR (Transact-SQL) and Built-in Functions (Transact-SQL). 
Conversion of float values that use scientific notation to decimal or numeric is restricted to values of precision 17 digits only. Any value with precision higher than 17 rounds to zero.*